# data sheet list view permission

Tags: list, permissions, list-view, datasheet, custom-list

I have created custom list on sharePoint 2007,
on that list I create data-sheet view.
I send a link to the "data-sheet list view" to some users,
in order that those user fill-in data.

I need to blocked the option to add new row.
is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom permission level that only gives users Edit Items permissions and apply that to a group of users in the list permissions.

[image: custom permission]